# macro definition

Tags: c, macros

I tried to define a macro functioned as below. Call 1 has no problem, but Call 2 prompted compiler error because 3rd argument is not available. How to define a macro which support both call 1 and call 2?

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, fmt, ...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " fmt, __VA_ARGS__))
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { /* printf debug message */ }

RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile); /* Call 1 */
RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient Memory\n"); /* call 2 , compiler -> error: expected expression before ')' token */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an extra comma in the second macro expansion, because you have an unconditional comma after `fmt` in the macro definition.

Dropping the `fmt` parameter from the macro definition seems to fix the problem; the format string then becomes part of `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, ...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " __VA_ARGS__))
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { /* printf debug message */ }

RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile); /* Call 1 */
RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient Memory\n");
```

This expands to:

```
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { }

(rdfDBG(kERROR, " " "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile));
(rdfDBG(kERROR, " " "Insufficient Memory\n"));
```

Incidentally, it looks like the `" "` is intended to require the format to be a string literal (and my modified version preserves this).  Are you sure you want to do that?  Though it's rare, it can be useful to have a non-literal format string.

Answer (score 2):

#### GCC Extensions

GCC has an extension to handle that (note the missing comma before the `...`):

Incorrect (references `__VA_ARGS__` which is not allowed in the GCC extension):

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, fmt ...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " fmt, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Correct (not referencing `__VA_ARGS__`):

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, fmt...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " fmt))
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { /* printf debug message */ }
enum { kERROR };

void x(const char *pinfile);
void x(const char *pinfile)
{
    RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile);
    RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient Memory\n");
}
```

You can tell I don't use the GCC extension - because I use some compilers that are not GCC.

There is also the second (GCC-specific) mechanism mentioned by Adam in his comment:

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, fmt, ...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " fmt, ## __VA_ARGS__))
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { /* printf debug message */ }
enum { kERROR };

void x(const char *pinfile);
void x(const char *pinfile)
{
    RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile);
    RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient Memory\n");
}
```

#### Standard C99

Failing that, you have to use the C99 standard mechanism:

```
#define RDF_LOG(dbglevel, ...) (rdfDBG(dbglevel, " " __VA_ARGS__))
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) { /* printf debug message */ }

RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Fail to open file %s\n", pinfile); /* Call 1 */
RDF_LOG(kERROR, "Insufficient Memory\n");
```

This basically cheats or circumvents the problem for this context.  In the general case, C99 requires a comma and at least one argument.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work.  Are you sure you're not thinking of the GCC extension where if you prepend `##` to `__VA_ARGS__` and zero arguments match the ellipsis, then it deletes the trailing comma?  E.g. `#define RDF_LOG(fmt, ...) foo(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)` results in `RDF_LOG("foo")` ==> `foo("foo")`.