# Is it possible to stringify a variadic macro?

Tags: c, macros

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Is it possible to stringify a variadic macro?

I have the following macro and I want to output the resulting string from the `fmt` and arguments.

```
#define ERROR_MESSAGE(priority, fmt, ...)        \
    do {                                         \
        MODULE_LOG(priority, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
} while(0)
```

So, I just want to get the complete string of the `fmt` and the `##__VA_ARGS__` so I can assign it to a `char *` to perform some additional operations on it.

Comment: The double-hash is the concatenation operator, not the stringify operator which is a single hash.

Comment: Variadic macros was introduced in C99

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: that use of `##` is a GCC extension which erases the comma before the `##` if the `__VA_ARGS__` list is empty.  There's a question about that somewhere on SO; I came across the notation in an answer I was rereading recently.  (One x-ref is [Macro definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788850/macro-definition/7788888#7788888); a better one is [C #define macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/1644898#1644898).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um, no. Preprocessing happens before the code is even compiled. It exists in a completely different universe from the executing program. One thing you can do, is run just the pre-processing step and examine the output (use the gcc switch `-E` to print the preprocessor output).

About the most you can do is to redirect this to a file, and then read the file in the program.

---

On further thought, let me back-off from "no", and change it to "maybe". Take a look at [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707148/foreach-macro-on-macros-arguments/6722112#6722112), that implements a "foreach" macro for variadic macros.

So, using `APPLYXn` (and, implicitly, `PPNARG`), you could apply a `STR(x) #x` macro to the args like this (n.b. as written, `APPLYXn` can handle up to 15 arguments):

```
#define X(x) #x
#define ERROR_MESSAGE(priority, fmt, ...)        \
    "do {MODULE_LOG(" X(priority) X(fmt) APPLYXn(__VA_ARGS__) ");} while(0)"

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", ERROR_MESSAGE(3, "%d", 5) );
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc -E` produces

```
# 1 "strvar.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "strvar.c"
# 71 "strvar.c"

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "do {MODULE_LOG(" "3" "\"%d\"" "5" ");} while(0)" );
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler will concatenate all these string literals into one string.